# Typescript function merge object at a specific path

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I have a merge function which merges objects at a specific path.

```js
const merge = (src, path, newObj) => {
   // this code works fine
}
```

To use this function I call it this way:

```js
interface IUser {
   user: {
      address: {
        street: string
      }
   }
}

interface IAddrNum {
   door: number
}

const User: IUser = {
   user: {
     address: {
        street: "New Street"
     }
   }
}


const mergeObj: IAddrNum = {
   door: 59
}

const newObj = merge(User, "user.address", mergeObj);
```

With that, I get the right result.

```
{
   user: {
     address: {
       street: "New Street"
       door: 59
     }
   }
}
```

Question: I want to create a signature for this function in typescript.

```js
interface Immutable {
   merge<T, K, M>(
     src: T,
     path: K,
     merge: M
   ): T & M // <== this is where the problem is
}
```

This does not work as expected. It cannot be `T & K` because the merge has to happen at the specific path. Is it possible to have a signature of this function ? If so, can you give me some direction. Thanks.

Comment: You can't do it with `"user.address"` since the compiler cannot parse strings at the type level.  Instead you would need to use something like tuples of the form `["user", "address"] as const` to even begin to write this.  Or you could make the `merge` parameter its own object like `{user: { address: {door: 59}}}` and not mention the path at all (in which case the return type really would look somewhat like `T & M`).  I'd be happy to advise on either of those options, but dotted path string literals are a non-starter.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz. I wasnt sure if the `"user.address"` would work. Thanks for explaining. I can make it `["user","address"]`. It would be great if you can guide me with this new change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're okay with using a path tuple, then we need to manipulate tuples.  A useful type alias is `Tail<T>` which takes a tuple type like `[string, number, boolean]` and returns another tuple with the first element removed, like `[number, boolean]`:

```
type Tail<T extends any[]> = 
  ((...t: T) => void) extends ((h: any, ...r: infer R) => void) ? R : never;
```

Then we can write `DeepRecord<K, V>` where `K` is a path of property keys, and `V` is some value.  We make a recursive mapped conditional type that produces an object type where `V` is located down into the path described by `K`:

```
type DeepRecord<K extends PropertyKey[], V> =
    K extends [] ? V : { [P in K[0]]: DeepRecord<Tail<K>, V> };
```

Just to make sure that works, here's an example"

```
type Example = DeepRecord<["foo", "bar", "baz"], string>;
/* type Example = { foo: { bar: { baz: string; }; };} */
```

Now we're essentially done, but it's also nice to make something that merges intersections recursively so that instead of `{foo: {bar: {baz: string}}} & {foo: {bar: {qux: number}}}` you get a single `{foo: {bar: {baz: string; qux: number;}}}`:

```
type MergeIntersection<T> = 
  T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: MergeIntersection<T[K]> } : T;
```

Finally, we can give `merge()` a type signature (and an implementation although that's out of the scope of the question and not guaranteed to be correct):

```
const merge = <T extends object, K extends N[] | [], 
  V extends object, N extends PropertyKey>(
    src: T, path: K, newObj: V
) => {
    const ret = { ...src } as MergeIntersection<T & DeepRecord<K, V>>;
    let obj: any = ret;
    for (let k of path) {
        if (!(k in obj)) {
            obj[k] = {};
        }
        obj = obj[k];
    }
    Object.assign(obj, newObj);
    return ret;
}
```

Note that `N` doesn't really do much in the definition, but it helps allow the compiler to infer that the `path` parameter constains [literals](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) and not just `string`.  And the `| []` in the constraint for `K` helps the compiler infer a tuple instead of an array.  You want `["user", "address"]` to be inferred as the type `["user", "address"]` instead of as `string[]` or the whole thing falls apart.  This annoying magic is the topic of [microsoft/TypeScript#30680](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680) and for now it's the best I can do.

You can test it on your example code:

```
const newObj = merge(User, ["user", "address"], mergeObj);
/* const newObj: {
    user: {
        address: {
            street: string;
            door: number;
        };
    };
}*/

console.log(JSON.stringify(newObj));
// {"user":{"address":{"street":"New Street","door":59}}}
```

Looks good I think.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-O1Rk9TTX8wQNGUIEYXTVCUfYTKuU5LLo6zCEeJQcrJX8YNcP4oECzKszM8jKPaljyvoxiurswoHI45EPlggbYuU1THB4saHxccY8X84tBDWFgkEEd5GAAKTc9N7RYEbUV3EBGFarkzx+b46j2Eq9g4Wo9h6yq7oeoa7uc1yPNLMsTj2Ca7qS8YgaAA)

Comment: Thank you @jcalz for the nice explanation and breaking it down for me to understand. This worked very well.

Comment: based on your code, I am trying to write  a type for `del`. In this case it would be `del(User, ["user","address","street"])`. Could you please guide me on this ? I have modifield the `DeepRecord` to create the object but I am not able to subtract this from the source object.

Comment: That's a different question, isn't it?  I'd be happy to look at it but not in the comments section (and you might want to post a new question anyway to get other eyes on it in case I can't get to it)

Comment: Sure, here is the link I just posted - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60529460/types-for-deleting-object-at-specific-nested-path