# Types for deleting object at specific nested path

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```js
type Tail<T extends any[]> = ((...t: T) => void) extends ((
  h: any,
  ...r: infer R
) => void)
  ? R
  : never;

type DeepOmit<T, Path extends string[]> = T extends object
  ? {
      0: Omit<T, Path[0]>;
      1: {
        [K in keyof T]: K extends Path[0] ? DeepOmit<T[K], Tail<Path>> : T[K];
      };
    }[Path['length'] extends 1 ? 0 : 1]
  : T;
```

I have the above type which works well. I have tested it this way:

```js
type A = DeepOmit<{ a: { b: { c: 1 } } }, ['a', 'b', 'c']>;

// {
//    a: {
//        b: Pick<{
//            c: 1;
//        }, never>;
//    };
// }
```

However when I add this inside a function, I dont get the desired output.

```js
const del = <T extends object, K extends string[]>(src: T, path: K) => {
  // custom logic removed. just creating the result below.
  const result = {
    a: {
      b: {}
    }
  }
  return result as DeepOmit<T, K>
};

const deletedObj = del({a:{b:{c:1}}},["a","b","c"]);
// deletedObj.a.b.c <========== still works
// expected is deletedObj.a.b
```

Can someone point me what is the issue here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that the compiler tends to widen tuples to arrays and literals to nonliterals unless you give it particular hints.  The *caller* of `del()` could use an `as const` assertion on the `path` parameter to get this effect (although you'd need to accept `readonly string[]` and not just `string[]`), but you presumably would like to have the caller not worry about it.  I've filed [microsoft/TypeScript#30680](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680) to ask for something like `as const` on the call signature to do this. In the absence of such a feature, you have to rely on some weird hints.

If you want an array type to be inferred as a tuple if possible, you should include a tuple type in its context, such as via a union.  So `T extends Foo[]` becomes `T extends Foo[] | []`.  If you want a type to be inferred as a string literal if possible, you should include a string literal in its context or some other `string`-like hint.  So `T extends string[]` becomes either `T extends (string | (""&{__:0}))[]` or, my preference, `T extends N[]` where `N` is another generic parameter `N extends string`.  Here's how it looks:

```
declare const del: <T extends object, K extends N[] | [], N extends string>(
    src: T, path: K
) => DeepOmit<T, K>;
```

And you can see it work as you intended:

```
const deletedObj = del({ a: { b: { c: 1 } } }, ["a", "b", "c"]);
deletedObj.a.b; // okay
deletedObj.a.b.c; // error
```

---

Also note that your definition of `DeepOmit` is unnecessarily roundabout; the `{0: X, 1: Y}[T extends U ? 0 : 1]` technique is a way of circumventing errors when `T extends U ? X : Y` is considered by the compiler to be circular (even though this sort of sidestepping is [not supported](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26223#issuecomment-513187373)). But the straightforward implementation of `DeepOmit` doesn't run afoul of those rules: it's fine to have a recursive type in which the recursion happens down in an object property:

```
type DeepOmit<T, Path extends string[]> = T extends object ?
    Path['length'] extends 1 ? Omit<T, Path[0]> : {
        [K in keyof T]: K extends Path[0] ? DeepOmit<T[K], Tail<Path>> : T[K];
    } : T; // no error, still works
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgSwDYB4ZQgD2BAdgEwGco5cQBtAXQD4oBeKACkYDo3gAuWASntoDcA9gny8sOAsWYBYAFBQFUABZdSIADRzFUNiwBOXBLgBmEPVABKc3nQHDRWxQH5LjhV1wR+ZgNxy5oJBQACIQEGAA8gC2CMBo6lAACnDAShjYeERQhMB6RgDmVLQM6OKZxIIARgBWEADGwFBObkkpSuQA5Eh4+akdlOkSWQCMTVDRsfGtqeQADDRQXADeLdrkANJQRlAA1hAggsawlFybZZLT7fNjoeETcTAblAnwyCjJqdS0XI-rlH7yRQAX0WsAB-lk+HqSDgemgdUEuByUChSC4aEG5SgVVqDQSZwyFwAclQoAAfKBUBJEzEXHJ5XD5aiMFqEPR1H4JMBtU7WPghMKRGIPfHUcGyBFIxqoiA4fARGr0FEQJCMJYkZZQSqajlQUYgg0JcgAIjgxoSxsq5qgxrqxso3ABMrlCuqLDgLEqPigAHofdidnAQHJnRB5TV3Z6WHVvX6MHo9II9BC5EA)

Comment: That's the correct one. I forgot about that we can take out the element type and inference will get better.

Comment: @jcalz thank you for your answer. The problem that I am facing is that all the methods are inside an interface. I understood the problem that you described and went to github to read more about it. Since I cannot declare const inside an interface, is their any other way I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is related with type inference of the second argument. In the type example type is strict as `['a','b','c']` but in the function argument is infered as `string[]`, so your type level function `DeepOmit` is called with `string[]` not with `['a','b','c']`. The result is the same as:

```
type Result = DeepOmit<{ a: { b: { c: 1 } } }, string[]>;
```

In order to fix it we need to or strictly type the variable by saying `['a','b','c'] as ['a','b','c']` which is very verbose, or we can make the function be more strict by treating every argument separately (using spread). The downside is that API of the function will change (I would say even for better ) a little bit, but inference works now as expected. Consider:

```
const del = <T extends object, K extends string[]>(src: T, ...path: K) => {
  // custom logic removed. just creating the result below.
  const result = {
    a: {
      b: {}
    }
  }
  return result as DeepOmit<T, K>
};

const deletedObj = del({ a: { b: { c: 1 } } }, 'a', 'b', 'c');
deletedObj.a.b.c // error no c !
```

Comment: Thanks Maciej. This works great, however, it is not an option for me to change the API. There are various methods which have the similar signature, so dont want to make an exception for this method.