# Typescript deep omit with dot notation

Tags: typescript, template-literals

As template literal types are now supported in TypeScript, is it possible to have something like the following?

```
interface Data {
  a: number;
  b: {
    c: number;
    d: number;
  }
}

type OmitDeep<T, K> = ...

type WithoutC = OmitDeep<Data, 'b.c'>
```

Where `WithoutC` will be inferred as:

```
interface WithoutC {
  a: number;
  b: {
   d: number
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this type to map dotted path to an array path:

```
type UnDot<T extends string> =
    T extends `${infer A}.${infer B}` ? [A, B] : ''

type ProperyArray = UnDot<'a.b'>; // ["a", "b"]
```

And then use this answer to remove nested properties:

[Types for deleting object at specific nested path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60529460/types-for-deleting-object-at-specific-nested-path)

Edit for any number of nesting levels:

```
type UnDot<T extends string> =
    T extends `${infer A}.${infer B}`
    ? [A, ...UnDot<B>]
    : [T];
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Roberto's wonderful answer, the full solution looks like this one:

```
type Tail<T extends any[]> = ((...t: T) => void) extends ((
    h: any,
    ...r: infer R
) => void)
    ? R
    : never;

type DeepOmit<T, Path extends string[]> = T extends object ?
    Path['length'] extends 1 ? Omit<T, Path[0]> : {
        [K in keyof T]: K extends Path[0] ? DeepOmit<T[K], Tail<Path>> : T[K];
    } : T;

type UnDot<T extends string> =
    T extends `${infer A}.${infer B}`
    ? [A, ...UnDot<B>]
    : [T];

type Nested = {
    a: number;
    b: {
        c: number;
        d: number;
    }
};

type Omitted =  DeepOmit<Nested, UnDot<'b.c'>>

const foo: Omitted = {a: 1, b: { c: 1, d: 2 } }; // error
                                 ~~~~
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgSwDYB4ZQgD2BAdgEwGco5cQBtAXQD4oBeKACkYDo3gAuWASntoDcA9gny8sOAsWYBYAFBQFUABZdSIADRzFUNiwBOXBLgBmEPVABKc3nQHDRWxQH5LjhV1wR+ZgNxy5oJBQACIQEGAA8gC2CMBo6lAACnDAShjYeERQhMB6RgDmVLQM6OKZxIIARgBWEADGwFBObkkpSuQA5Eh4+akdlOkSWQCMTVDRsfGtqeQADDRQXADeLdrkANJQRlAA1hAggsawlFybZZLT7fNjoeETcTAblAnwyCjJqdS0XI-rlH7yRQAX0WsABAXA0AAqrhgoIHoNytlcgVii1ShkLgADAAkSyMpnMAEEgSw8QSzFAAEJArEtFzkIkJXQwuFxKnUSgtLjkGD-fyyQLQAByEByEHw9CgK0BCjgHgArlFKr4WpVlqtFHVFcrVbLtFB8DqVXoAdogXIgeDBZDxjFgDhJQwQmFIvaUKLxfgEqz4SgOpUWHUOl8BXVBLgclBjIJBFx7o6pUt5VBhgl1dKoNrUwkjVAAExQEFWqAAelLGD0ekEeiAA)

Comment: You can edit your answer with the better `UnDot` implementation from my edit