# TypeScript - Generics do not match

Tags: typescript

In the below ([and attached](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAsBdIBwZwFwgLYFMAmBLArsgdAMYD2ywAHgOaqoDWcwkAnjKnAQE6YyQC02kmADaYmPGqkZEAZjwB2rSBh5EARgCtUBXlICGAZlQAWAKwB2VFIBMKywCgmLUABFqMANISA8lIA8AFQA%20UABeUABvW1Ao0ABtD0ZQTFlQcUkpUD9QADJQAAo4SE5ZClAAH1BZXBVUdgBKAF0EDLiJetBUMkVZdDhQVQ0tUAB%20UAADABIw%20IBfUbKxyZm8SZdUdy9fPxbGeoDZ0CaJqYlZ22mY1OkM7LyCopLyyuRquvqAbltbEGdXT2QRUAAdyI7DooB0vQ6LC0GFAPAg0HgSGABR0BBoRAAbjUpIIiIDCCRgDpgKZjAAOSx6ABsAEZTMA9HpLABOUzUgAM9mYqB%20az%20In8ABpQG52p1UN1egAFdhEFjsJjxIKhCLRWLSxLJS7pTIQ0CajpdHqi4YVVDY9gHA2NPkwAWQfwxaX1EVio2Sk1HACiZAIgmw6FQPmlIrgjGeREEe2WYSSUhqoAASvsRknrfJLQEzp9vgBhEgqJJJEqrdaMbzg7p2h1AkFghUJrSCRgAQm5jjLDsU6G9sgETH8fYHCQ9UtAAEkAEIQ1DDkSMEV%20AVwOCYIiySES8dl%20LeIf9hcBFU1-6OvzzpgigBEmHQ1-my-%20q-Xm4CH1sSUU7F0BF509nS8EjVaI7yaO4Sw%20dVkBBVBwMKSDImiIhIHAGp4PuD5plzMA-HATBemBUFen1KFNB7WxiE3SBQDgEhUE8dRyKaLszx7ICfAAuA50PK9QGvGD2FQa8TxAqIULQ9gmmvVCCLrYjrxzL5cLQ8F0HQUA0FQogNPQIhWAqFDQGEcQMhXNcNzgT9%20xxNFeQAWUYCcbJ-OyDxHcVjV6LieJHJdzNfLcvLtPdNiA49wiQqIdHU3JJQHTBWBY342IwDiL14xczOfCy3xiepaiaTEiDvLCgA)) example, I am trying to pass nested type omissions using generics with the type `DeepKeyOf<T>`.  On it's own, `DeepKeyOf<T>` works as expected, it's only when I try to pass around generics that extend `DeepKeyOf<T>` that it doesn't work.

Below, I have `MyInterface<TEntity extends IBaseEntity, TOmissions extends DeepKeyOf<TEntity>>`, which is trying to take in `TOmissions` and pass those to `DeepOmittedEntity`.  As far as I can tell the types line up, what am I missing?

```js
// https://medium.com/xgeeks/typescript-utility-keyof-nested-object-fa3e457ef2b2
type DeepKeyOf<T> = {
    [Key in keyof T & (string | number)]: T[Key] extends object ? `${Key}` | `${Key}.${DeepKeyOf<T[Key]>}` : `${Key}`
}[keyof T & (string | number)];

// DeepOmit works as expected - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75823617/3329760
type DeepOmit<T, K extends PropertyKey> = {
    [P in keyof T as P extends K ? never : P]: DeepOmit<T[P], K extends `${Exclude<P, symbol>}.${infer R}` ? R : never>
}

// Combining DeepKeyOf and DeepOmit works perfectly!
type DeepOmittedEntity<TEntity extends IBaseEntity, TOmissions extends DeepKeyOf<TEntity>> = DeepOmit<TEntity, "id" | TOmissions>;

interface IBaseEntity {
    id: string;
    more: string;
    other: string;
}

// This works as expected
const someObject: DeepOmittedEntity<IBaseEntity, "more"> = {
    other: "this works"
}

// The add method does not like TOmissions - see linked example
interface MyInterface<TEntity extends IBaseEntity, TOmissions extends DeepKeyOf<TEntity>> {
    add(entities: DeepOmittedEntity<TEntity, TOmissions>[]): void;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAsBdIBwZwFwgLYFMAmBLArsgdAMYD2ywAHgOaqoDWcwkAnjKnAQE6YyQC02kmADaYmPGqkZEAZjwB2rSBh5EARgCtUBXlICGAZlQAWAKwB2VFIBMKywCgmLUABFqMANISA8lIA8AFQA%20UABeUABvW1Ao0ABtD0ZQTFlQcUkpUD9QADJQAAo4SE5ZClAAH1BZXBVUdgBKAF0EDLiJetBUMkVZdDhQVQ0tUAB%20UAADABIw%20IBfUbKxyZm8SZdUdy9fPxbGeoDZ0CaJqYlZ22mY1OkM7LyCopLyyuRquvqAbltbEGdXT2QRUAAdyI7DooB0vQ6LC0GFAPAg0HgSGABR0BBoRAAbjUpIIiIDCCRgDpgKZjAAOSx6ABsAEZTMA9HpLABOUzUgAM9mYqB%20az%20In8ABpQG52p1UN1egAFdhEFjsJjxIKhCLRWLSxLJS7pTIQ0CajpdHqi4YVVDY9gHA2NPkwAWQfwxaX1EVio2Sk1HACiZAIgmw6FQPmlIrgjGeREEe2WYSSUhqoAASvsRknrfJLQEzp9vgBhEgqJJJEqrdaMbzg7p2h1AkFghUJrSCRgAQm5jjLDsU6G9sgETH8fYHCQ9UtAAEkAEIQ1DDkSMEV%20AVwOCYIiySES8dl%20LeIf9hcBFU1-6OvzzpgigBEmHQ1-my-%20q-Xm4CH1sSUU7F0BF509nS8EjVaI7yaO4Sw%20dVkBBVBwMKSDImiIhIHAGp4PuD5plzMA-HATBemBUFen1KFNB7WxiE3SBQDgEhUE8dRyKaLszx7ICfAAuA50PK9QGvGD2FQa8TxAqIULQ9gmmvVCCLrYjrxzL5cLQ8F0HQUA0FQogNPQIhWAqFDQGEcQMhXNcNzgT9%20xxNFeQAWUYCcbJ-OyDxHcVjV6LieJHJdzNfLcvLtPdNiA49wiQqIdHU3JJQHTBWBY342IwDiL14xczOfCy3xiepaiaTEiDvLCgA)

**EDIT 1:**

If I replace `DeepKeyOf<T>` with `string`, everything works, but the intellisense doesn't work for obvious reasons.