# Make some (nested) properties optional

Tags: typescript

In a TypeScript project, there's a type definition like this:

```js
type Foo = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  metadata: {
    c: string;
    d: string;
  };
};
```

It's imported from elsewhere and used a lot elsewhere, so I can't change it.

I'd like to create a function that takes a `Foo` as its parameter, but with `a` and `metadata.c` being optional because I can set meaningful default values for those fields in this context:

```js
function doSomething(foo: {
  a?: string;
  b: string;
  metadata: {
    c?: string;
    d: string;
  };
}): void {
  // do whatever
}
```

The actual type is a lot bigger though and gets updated from time to time, so completely copying its definition to add two question marks is not an option.

Here's what I've tried:

```js
Foo & { a?: string; metadata: { c?: string } }
```

Doesn't work because this creates a type that is a `Foo` and a `{ a?: string; metadata: { c?: string } }` at the same time. This is basically just `Foo` because the required properties of `Foo` "win". Would probably work if I had the inverse problem (optional properties in `Foo` that are required here).

```js
Exclude<Foo, { a?: string; metadata: { c?: string } }>
```

Doesn't work because `Foo` is not a type union, and `Exclude` can only exclude types from type unions. It can't "subtract" individual properties from a type defined by a type literal.

```js
Partial<Foo>
```

Makes all properties of `Foo` optional. I don't want that.

```js
Omit<Foo, 'a'> & { a?: string }
```

`Omit` successfully removes `a` from `Foo`. I can then add `a` back in as an optional property. However, I don't know what to do about `c` because it is nested inside `metadata`.

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Does extending works? a.k.a. `interface B extends A` and then declare the differences on the new interface

Comment: See if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55032655/10473393

Comment: Not a "no modification" fix but when I've faced similar nested property issues before, I made the metadata object its own type `FooMetadata`. For this you can (e.g.) omit `metadata` and re-add its type with `c` omitted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a single property optional in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43159887/make-a-single-property-optional-in-typescript)

Comment: @ExaltedToast The real type definition I'm working with actually does that already, so I can I use that together with the accepted answer below!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can derive a type from `Foo` for the `doSomething` parameter, without modifying `Foo`. Because TypeScript's type system is structural (based on the shapes of types), not nominal (based on the names/identities of shapes), you can keep `Foo` assignment-compatible to your new type, meaning you can pass `Foo`-typed arguments to `doSomething`, but you can *also* pass arguments with your new type.

Here's one way to define the new type — note that we get all the type information from `Foo` other than what we need to adjust `a` and `metadata.c`:

```
type SpecialFoo = Omit<Foo, "a" | "metadata"> & {
    a?: Foo["a"];
    metadata: Omit<Foo["metadata"], "c"> & {
        c?: Foo["metadata"]["c"];
    };
};
```

Then `doSomething` accepts one of those:

```
function doSomething(foo: SpecialFoo): void {
    // do whatever
    console.log(foo);
}
```

With that, these work:

```
// Works
doSomething({ b: "b", metadata: { d: "d" } });
// Works
doSomething({ a: "a", b: "b", metadata: { c: "c", d: "d" } });
```

But as one would want, these examples with invalid values for `a` and `c` don't work:

```
// Error as desired, `a` has the wrong type
doSomething({ a: 42, b: "b", metadata: { d: "d" } });
// Error as desired, `c` has the wrong type
doSomething({ b: "b", metadata: { c: 42, d: "d" } });
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFLUCGAuKAZ2ACcBLAOwHMBuTbAIwOPOruygFsJgcATHLwIYOHAMbNSlWvVFQ+k1jI4BfOmvTpQkKAGVIYsjgA28RCgDynMsAA8ZgDRQARDmdQAPi+68BvZwB8UABkaLK4APwEZgDars4AuuzYPvyC+FBWNvYIcal+bglOzmKBIWFyWGJRsLnO+emJcaVJ4Roa6ABmAK4UYsBkcBTycLpwPgAW0gAUnQgE+hCGJmYAlAQAbnBkfBXYAPT7I1AA7hOCEBsQJOFiQ4RwxhAAdMZwVLMIq+qah1AA6nASABrQjoPijcY8KbUaaoKBMFwMZxOBpCNDyAjOPjuFRQFTfdB-QEgsEQsaTGbwjLxJyI5zI1E8NLo+ESFylJwKFw4-H4wl-ACiJBIQNwhHkEEIZBIED4TgABjgFVBzhLgBNoCdRdQoNoIODIZTYdSCAAWABMdKxjK4zIKwkxPNx-LoQpFYpwEr4UplcsVYhVar1mtOOqoevABvJUI1VIRNpRdt86Ud7MtXKxvLxBJoQA)

Comment: I was still hoping for something that looks a little more clean and concise, but it gets the job done. I didn't know about the `Foo["metadata"]` syntax. Thanks!

Comment: @Rapti - I'm sure it's possible to write something more elegant that would let you do `type SpecialFoo = OmitDeep<Foo, "a" | "metadata.c">;`. The complexity may be problematic. I messed up my initial search for duplicates when I saw your question, but [this search](/search?q=%5Btypescript%5D+omit+deep) finds several prior posts that may help, particularly [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75823617/157247) (jcalz **really** knows TS) but also answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67785778/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67884720/) and probably others. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder for `OmitDeep` there is [`type-fest`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest)'s [`OmitDeep`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/omit-deep.d.ts)

Comment: @ghybs - Nice, thanks! Looks like a very handy lib!

Answer (score 1):

We can leverage the [`MergeDeep`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/merge-deep.d.ts) utility type from [`type-fest`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest):

> Merge two objects or two arrays/tuples recursively into a new type.

While not explicitly documented, the `?` optional flags of the source type are also ported.

In your case, it simplifies the construction of some optional nested properties of a complex object:

```
type Bar = {
    a?: string;
    metadata: {
        c?: string;
    }
};

type SpecialFoo = MergeDeep<Foo, Bar>;
//   ^? { b: string; a?: string | undefined; metadata: { d: string; c?: string | undefined; }; }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgWQKZQOaoCKtWOAXzgDMoIQ4AiGATzFQFoTUBnGKgbgChu6G4AMQgQ4AXkTc40uAEMAXHHZRgAOww8ZcAEaLlajVJkhUMWQBNZZxQiNbpAYz0wV6zfennnrw1sI9-Xn5UOAAhWShxSS1ZAH5vA3dpAHpk3SUXRLs4EzNLa2iPOAd4jJ8k+1SvMqy-bkC+ehCAZQYHYFkAG2FRCTRMHDwwAB4egBowiIA+HlSZAD1Y3hIAV1UHGGAIVThzCGaKUwALAwAKEhFFVtR2rp6ASkUANwhgc0KU5N3RAHcjq1QT3Q2Qc21YEE6qAAdJ0IBhziJ7gFeHMAOrQADWrG4ewOuRO6lOSHSVG0VAmuQsVgUiF2iio5ioRCISJRX3RUCxOP2hxgBPhSBpVFk5J09LJFNMVIKSCc1AcouqDKZxEIrO4cwAolByJFZKxdmxgFBUOYJgADWTmuD-A18kI-cjqODBbl445nQWKAAsACYJiSJTkpfkaUglYzmWrZl9tbq5AbzEaTWa4OaHNbbS6jg6nRgXU03bz+USxdQg5TQzZij7-XTqJHVaygA)

---

It would be tempting to specify the optional nested keys as a *union of paths* (e.g. `"a" | "metadata.c"`), instead of the above `Bar` type. That would avoid having to re-specify the type of the values, in particular.

Especially given that `type-fest` already offers [`PickDeep`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/pick-deep.d.ts) and [`Paths`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/paths.d.ts) utility types.

But unfortunately, it is not trivial to set only the *final part* of these paths as optional: a simple [`PartialDeep`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/partial-deep.d.ts) also turns all intermediate keys as optional as well, which you may not want. In your example, `metadata` remains required for instance:

```
type SetOptionalDeep<T, PathUnion extends Paths<T>> =
    MergeDeep<T, PartialDeep<PickDeep<T, PathUnion>>>;

type SpecialFoo = SetOptionalDeep<Foo, "a" | "metadata.c">;
//   ^? { b: string; a?: string | undefined; metadata?: { d: string; c?: string | undefined; } | undefined; }

function doSomething(foo: SpecialFoo): void {}

// Should not have been fine: we still want "metadata" to be required
doSomething({ b: "b" });
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgWQKZQOaoCKtWAGjgAUBDWYUgG13yLJgAsBne4AYwGtaw4BfOADMoEEHABEMAJ5hUAWkGpmMcQG4AUOumy4AMQgQ4AXkTq45uKQBccZVGAA7DBotwARjbuPnZiyFQwpAAmpIE2CL6u5uyeMPZOLlHmQbHxPq58Gpma2qhwAMoBAPJgMMAQDtQ8ADwAKvShLACqDuUOcKgAHjCoDkHMJI3MdQB8I8aRKOhYNfWDFFV4YNXEHNxLdQ1MzC1tYyMaWjJ5+bLslFT6hiaFMCVlFYv41VdE4qTicAA+Ev6BIYEAHTscQHdQAenBFgAegB+TSCACuDnYD3aQQg+VEAUY3gAFIIDDZTqhztQrgBKGwANwgwCCplckLgGLgAHdGKFUNT0JN2BVmBAqKhAVQIBgCQYKVlNMyAOrQTjMdQYrF-XFOPFIDwSNziIh-YKhayIFk2cRBT4CPjS2VQ-KMCCIqgMhwQeCcnnuPDtQSOVA2Nl5ZTAKhUdmkBzwcSGgEfOAwQxuPJQVAAR0RwFTQRVmOxTHx2vNev4tohUIVUCVubVOMLlnNHyIOvEeoNASNYVNMQkIKIKQklv4pcOzIAolARFBLAMgkos6ggkQAAakZdwTkDJh5NkiJwJ441-MaiVIE0AFgATM3i-q4LHjeEzYOrSPy3AJ1OZyz59mV+x103BNGB3PcMAPWQj3VesWzbe8OzjJ8eyvftzSHa1bSAA)

At least in your very example, since `metadata` key is at the top-level, we could simply make it back as required with [`SetRequired`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/set-required.d.ts):

```
type SpecialFoo = SetRequired<SetOptionalDeep<Foo, "a" | "metadata.c">, "metadata">;
//   ^? { b: string; a?: string | undefined; metadata: { d: string; c?: string | undefined; }; }

// Error as desired: we still want "metadata" to be required
doSomething({ b: "b" });
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-brbo9iS9Y5ldbngeDS4j0FXWNmDLLd2F3fcz0YI8TwwM97gve1uwHF9hzfHEPwnB9py-AMFwsIA)